# Why isn't the transition property working on this linear gradient?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have included a jsfiddle to simplify this.
The problem is that when the mouse hovers on the arrows, the transition is not animating as expected.

```
.spotlight-next {
  transition: background 0.5s ease-out;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}

.spotlight-next:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yashiman/jqq3u1nz/2/

Comment: tip: instead of the fiddle you can use the embedded html+css(+js) engine. question: what do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linear-gradient` works like `background-image`, and how you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp), **`background-image` is not *animatable***.

This is pretty obvious, because there's no a standard way to animate a `background-image`. You could want to animate it with a *fade-in* effect or with a *swipe-left* effect, this is ambigous and I don't understand why you say it doesn't work "as expected". What was expected?

You should leverage on setting transition for other properties, like `opacity` or `width`.

---

This is an easy way to implement a fade effect on the `background-image` property, using the `::after` pseudo-element:

```
.spotlight-next::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  opacity: 0.1;
  z-index: -1;
}
.spotlight-next:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

remove `transition` and `background-image` property from `.spotlight-next` in order to make it work.

Comment: I was trying to get a smooth fade on hover, but I guess opacity animations should do the trick. Thanks

Comment: @YashA I updated the answer with a tip to implement it